# UNION SELECT is faster than a VIEW of the same query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, database-performance, union-all

my Query is

```
select * from `database_1`.`table_name` 
union all 
select * from `database_2`.`table_name`;
```

this Query Run In 0.0074 - 0.0170 seconds

But when create View with this Query

```
create View `view_name` as 
    select * from `database_1`.`table_name` 
    union all 
    select * from `database_2`.`table_name`;


select * from `view_name`;
```

this Query Run In 0.0800 - 0.1200 seconds

> Notice: this view is on tow databases.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, mysql views are not particularly great. It probably materialises the union results in a temporary table.

Comment: In dig data base when query run in 0.1 seconds run view in 15 seconds .

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the two cases.